# Flash DataGrid - Sorting Arrows always visible

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sorting, datagrid

I'd like to set up my DataGrid so that the sorting arrows are always on the header, not just whenever you click on one.

At minimum I'd like to force one column to start off sorted and have the arrows show up on that column. The main point is to give the user an idea that the columns are sortable via those arrows (to those whom it's not already obvious, which doesn't include me).

Thanks!
Will

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you can only show one arrow, on the column that is being used currently to sort the datagrid. To force the arrow to show up on one column without any click, you can sort the datagrid by one default column after it has been created, using the `creationComplete` event callback.

The code to create the default sorting would be something like (inside `mx:script` tags):

```
import mx.collections.Sort;
import mx.collections.SortField;

private function init():void
{
  dataProvider.sort = new Sort();
  dataProvider.sort.fields = [new SortField("field_to_sort_on", false, true)];
  dataProvider.refresh();
}
```

You can check a working example here: [Displaying the sort arrow in a Flex DataGrid control without having to click a column](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/02/28/displaying-the-sort-arrow-in-a-flex-datagrid-control-without-having-to-click-a-column/) on the [Flex Examples blog](http://blog.flexexamples.com/), which is a great resource to learn Flex. Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, standard DataGrid can only sort by one column. To make sorting by several columns, one need some custom grid with complex sorting. And then you have issues like "What is first sort criteria and what is second?", which may require numbers next to arrows.